# Нужна помощь в оптимизации запроса MySQL

Tags: mysql, opencart3.x

Имеется такой запрос время выполнения больше трех секунд:

```
SELECT MAX(a.attribute_id) attribute_id, MAX(ad.name) attribute_name, MAX(pa.text) value, COUNT(*) total 
FROM `oc_product` p 
LEFT JOIN `oc_product_attribute` pa ON (p.product_id = pa.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN `oc_attribute` a ON (a.attribute_id = pa.attribute_id) 
LEFT JOIN `oc_attribute_description` ad ON (ad.attribute_id = a.attribute_id) 
LEFT JOIN `oc_product_description` pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN `oc_product_to_store` p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0' AND pd.language_id = '1' AND pa.language_id = '1' AND ad.language_id = '1' 
GROUP BY lower(pa.text), a.attribute_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

результатом запроса является таблица для фильтра товаров

Создал доступ playground базе данных:

```
https://server78.hosting.reg.ru/phpmyadmin/db_sql.php?db=u1110934_forum
USER: u1110934_forum
PASS: forum1221
```

Я думаю это из-за того что запрос перебирает всю таблицу oc_product_attribute без индексов, не знаю как это решить, помогите пожалуйста.

Я добавил индексы в таблице oc_product_attribute на столбцы attribute_id и product_id, но насколько мне известно mysql запросы опираются на один индекс и тут нужно составной индекс, по трем колонкам, attribute_id, product_id и language_id, который уже имеется.

Также не могу понять подробно сам запрос, для чего MAX(a.attribute_id), MAX(ad.name, MAX(pa.text)
И как именно происходит подсчет.